# How to find values smaller than another value in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have an html file with subtitles and their position on screen.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
<p begin="00:00:01.909" end="00:00:04.118" tts:origin="12.500% 84.667%">
  <span><span>Housewives of Beverly Hills"...<style tts:backgroundColor="#000000FF" tts:fontSize="18px" tts:fontStyle="italic"/> </span>
  <style tts:backgroundColor="#000000FF" tts:fontSize="18px"/></span>
</p>
<p begin="00:00:04.196" end="00:00:05.745" tts:origin="10.000% 84.667%">
  <span>- My husband has an RV.
  <style tts:backgroundColor="#000000FF" tts:fontSize="18px"/></span>
</p>
<p begin="00:00:05.822" end="00:00:07.413" tts:origin="10.000% 79.333%">
  <span>I think we should do
  <style tts:backgroundColor="#000000FF" tts:fontSize="18px"/></span>
</p>
```

I would like to find all values **under** "15.000%" in Notepad++
How can I do it?

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x72t49wywyseeut/index_4_av_FF1.ttml?dl=0) you'll find the whole file content in case you need it to inspect.

Comment: Do you just want to find the value, or the element containing that value?

Comment: Just the element containing that value. Thanks

Comment: Please, add some real code instead of a screenshort. So we can better test the regexes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: What exactly must be selected? Whole `<p>` tags? Just the opening `<p>` tag? Perhaps just the subtitle text? Please, show us the way :-)

Comment: I just want to highlight all numbers lower than 15.000 in the text. These lines will show all subtitles lines where I need to modify the positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try searching on the following regex pattern:

```
(?:1[0-4]|[0-9])(?:\.\d+)?%
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you, but when I put my text in the "Test string" field, it don't find anything.

Comment: Are you searching in regex mode?  Click the regex search option and try again.

Comment: I think you should add a word boundary. Besides that, I think this regex should work if OP just wants to select the number. @Hakunamatata67, this should work... Have you tried with 'regex mode'?

Comment: Sorry for being dumb, but where's the regex search option to activate the 'regex mode'?

Comment: When you press `CTRL` + `F` the dialog box which pops up should have a button for choosing regex mode.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the 'Regex mode' option (I'm using Firefox)

Comment: Then why did you tag your question with Notepad++?